# Serial downvotes

Tags: support, serial-voting

I would like to report a massive downvote of answers of mine today as visible in my profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2013-05-08%2020:09:16Z

[image]

Could you please verify the case?

Comment: Serial downvotes get reverted once a day. Did you never got serial voted before having 440k rep?

Comment: As a long standing user you do know that that gets reverted automatically, right? The moderators cannot see who downvoted you either.

Comment: No, I don't know that. I never got serial downvotes before.

Comment: That *is* amazing, if true.

Comment: Do you think I would have requested moderator attention if I knew that? Anyway, thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov All five of us who voted to close that question were serially downvoted. He downvoted you even more than the rest of us because you commented I think. I flagged his post mentioning that and the swearing.

Comment: @Zenith, that explains it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: "I never got serial downvotes before." You lucky son of a...

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: With your position plus long history on the Stack Overflow leaderboard I'd have thought you'd have experienced this by now. You've been lucky!

Comment: Wow... I've gotten serial downvotes twice before :P

Comment: I'm not shure if `I suppose by the ...` which might be wrong and an be read by everyone should mentioned ...

Comment: Please do not downvote us for closing this question as a duplicate :)

Comment: I processed your flag on the post that kicked off this downvoting spree a little while ago. Unfortunately, we can't reply to a flag without *declining* it, so there was no good way to message you.  I did verify the downvotes were from one user and they've now been warned. The downvotes should disappear automatically within a day or so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wait for about 24 hours. If you don't see an entry in your rep history called "serial downvoting reversed", then flag one of your posts with an explanation of what happened.

For a more in-depth look, see [the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) that was suggested.